# adding two sort icons to a datatables column?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, datatables

So let's say one of my datatable columns is something like "Vehicle Make / Model" and that the values are formatted like "Toyota
Camry".

Superficially, it'd be better if these were two columns but I have limited screen real-estate and I'd rather people scroll vertically than horizontally.

For now I've disabled sorting on the "Vehicle Make / Model" column by doing `'columnDefs': [{orderable: false, target: x}]` but what I'd like to do is to make it so that it looks more like this:

Vehicle Make ↕ / Model ↕

eg. one column with two sortable widgets within it.

The image itself is `images/sort_both.png` (or sort_asc.png or sort_desc.png) but just because the image is there doesn't make it sortable..

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll have to split it into two arrays to sort it separately, and since you're using datatables, you might as well do it beforehand, and get yourself two columns.

## Fix the source data

If you have no control over the format of the source-data, then you're likely out of luck. 
Consider, where would you split the results in the following case:

```
Make          Model         Your Make/Model Column

Hyundai       Santa Fe      Hyundai Santa Fe
Alfa Romeo    Giulietta     Alfa Romeo Giulietta
```

## Style the columns

Then, you can have 3 columns: `Make, Model, Make/Model`.
Just set `display:none` on Make and Model, but use them for sorting.

#### sort on the hidden columns

```
var modelSortAsc = true;

$('#modelColumnLink').click(function(){
    var sort = (modelSortAsc)? "asc" : "desc";
    modelSortAsc = !modelSortAsc;
    DataTable( {
        "order": [[ 4, sort ]]
    } );
});
```

Comment: I have control over the source data. The reason I'm displaying it as "Hyundai<br>Sante Fe" is because of limited screen real estate. If the idea is include the make and model in separate columns that are hidden whilst retaining the combined column I'd be fine with that if that would actually help..

Comment: Exactly as you described. Make the two columns hidden.